# How to idle a rarely used HDD

Tags: hard-drive

On my desktop PC, beside the main HDD with the master-partition I also use a separate HDD which I actually access quite rarely, say once a week.

So I want to know if there's any application utility out there which can let me stop the HDD when I don't need it running and restart it when I need it.
I want to reduce both the overall power consumption and the wear of the disk.

Thanks.

Comment: Please retag your question with the operating system you want to achieve this with or add more info to the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using GNU/Linux try usingf hdparm  (e.g. `hdparm -S180`) If you use an other OS please mention that in the post or tag your post with that OS.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Windows, just the configure power-management settings <sup>[[1]](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/Power-plans-frequently-asked-questions) [[2]](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/products/features/power-management) [[3]](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/9090/learning-windows-7-manage-power-settings/)</sup> to turn off the drives after about five minutes instead of the default 15 or so. Windows will know the other drive hasn’t been used in a while and shut it down, while the the drive that is continually being used will continue to run (I don’t think the system drive *ever* shuts down).